# Aligning Component to Right side of parent component

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

[image]

I want to align JDialog component to right as shown above. I have tried with by setting setLocationRelativeTo(**parent**)`. But it align it to the left.. Any help on this regards highly appreciated

**EDIT**

```
JDialog exDialog = new JDialog();
exDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(ParentFrame);
exDialog.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: 1) *"I have tried.."* For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) *"to left as shown above"* If the small rectangle represents the dialog, it's on the right. 3) *"I want to align JDialog component to left.."* Why? That's an unusual requirement.

Comment: Another nice edit. But where is the MRE / SSCCE? Uncompilable code snippets are **not** an MRE / SSCCE. Did you actually *read* the linked documents or are you just guessing based on the names?

Comment: The [setLocationRelativeTo method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationRelativeTo-java.awt.Component-) of the Window class will attempt to center the JDialog in the parent component.  To shift your JDialog all the way to the left, you either have to center the JDialog over a leftmost JPanel or calculate the bounds of the JDialog yourself and use the setBounds method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        var parent = new JFrame("Alignment");
        parent.setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
        parent.setVisible(true);
        parent.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        var dialog = new JDialog(parent);
        dialog.setSize(480, 320);
        var parentLocation = parent.getLocationOnScreen();
        dialog.setLocation(
                parentLocation.x + parent.getWidth() - dialog.getWidth() - 10,
                parentLocation.y + parent.getHeight()/2 - dialog.getHeight()/2);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    });
}
```